# Checkpatch Macro Error

Tags: c, macros

I get the following error, when using `chechpatch.pl` on my C code:

> main.c:14: ERROR: Macros with complex values should be enclosed in parentheses

The macro itself:

```
#define CHECK(x, y) if (x) { \
                            perror(y); \
                            exit(-1); }

/* USAGE */
CHECK((dup2(in, 0) < 0), "dup2"); //or just (dup2(in, 0) < 0, "dup2")
```

just a simple perror-check to shorten my code and save some work. `x` is a condition and `y` is string literal.

Is it a false positive?

However, I really want to fixed it, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some fight (uneven) with both the compiler and checkpatch, I went to the C-macro basics and got it right. Since, I didn't found much information about my issue, I will leave it here.

First, I tried with brackets around the value, but since it is an if-statement it unravels pretty awkwardly, giving `error: expected expression before ‘if’`.

Then, of course, I had missed a bracket, resulting in `error: expected ‘while’ before ‘if’`. So, the correct way is

```
#define CHECK(x, y) do { if (x) {perror(y); exit(-1); } } while (0)
```

in this way the expression remains intact and checkpatch shuts up.

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated a little bit and found no reason why checkpatch complains about this, so I reported a bug:
http://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg2484676.html

It turns out the problem comes when you use that macro inside an if-else statement like this:

```
if (foo())
    CHECK(x, y);
else
    do_smomething();
```

So, checkpatch's complain seems to be legit and we should use `do { ... } while (0)` after all.

I hope this helps.